# I'm trying to get japanese sentences with python 3.8. but I'm just gettting non-intelligible characters, somebody can help me?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, unicode, cjk

I'm using this python script

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/sentences.cfm?j=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97&e=&search=Search+%3E')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


sentences = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sentence"]/div[@class="sm"]/div[@class="jp"]/text()')
print ('Sentences: ', sentences)
```

and I'm getting this

```
Sentences:  ['ä»\x8aæ\x97¥ã\x81¯æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®æ\x9b¸ã\x81\x8då\x8f\x96ã\x82\x8aã\x81\x8cã\x81\x82ã\x82\x8bã\x80\x82', 'æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92æ\x9b¸ã\x81\x8fã\x81¨ã\x81\x8dã\x81¯ç\x82¹ã\x82\x84ã\x81¯ã\x82\x89ã\x81\x84ã\x81«æ°\x97ã\x82\x92ã\x81¤ã\x81\x91ã\x81¦ã\x80\x81ã\x81ªã\x82\x8bã\x81¹ã\x81\x8fæ\x97©ã\x81\x8fã\x81¦ã\x81\x84ã\x81\xadã\x81\x84ã\x81«æ\x9b¸ã\x81\x8dã\x81¾ã\x81\x97ã\x82\x87ã\x81\x86ã\x80\x82', 'æ¨ªç\x9d\x80ã\x81\x97ã\x81ªã\x81\x84ã\x81§ã\x80\x81æ\x95\x99ã\x82\x8fã\x81£ã\x81\x9fæ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92ä½¿ã\x81\x84ã\x81ªã\x81\x95ã\x81\x84ã\x80\x82', 'ã\x80\x8cé\x81\x93ã\x80\x8dã\x81¨ã\x81\x84ã\x81\x86æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®ç·\x8fç\x94»æ\x95°ã\x81¯ä½\x95ç\x94»ã\x81§ã\x81\x99ã\x81\x8bã\x80\x82', 'å½¼ã\x81¯æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81\x8cå\x85¨ã\x81\x8fæ\x9b¸ã\x81\x91ã\x81ªã\x81\x84ã\x80\x82', 'å\x90\x9bã\x81¯ã\x81\x93ã\x81®æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81\x8cèª\xadã\x82\x81ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x81\x8bã\x80\x82', 'æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81¯èª\xadã\x82\x80ã\x81®ã\x81\x8cé\x9b£ã\x81\x97ã\x81\x84ã\x80\x82', 'ã\x81\x93ã\x81®æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81¯ã\x81©ã\x81\x86ã\x81\x84ã\x81\x86æ\x84\x8få\x91³ã\x81§ã\x81\x99ã\x81\x8bã\x80\x82', 'ã\x81\x84ã\x81\x8bã\x81«ã\x82\x82ã\x83ªã\x82¾ã\x83¼ã\x83\x88ã\x81£ã\x81¦ã\x81\x8bã\x82\x93ã\x81\x98ã\x81®æ\xa0¼å¥½ã\x81\xadã\x80\x82', 'æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92å°\x91ã\x81\x97æ\x95\x99ã\x81\x88ã\x81¦ã\x81\x8fã\x81\xa0ã\x81\x95ã\x81\x84ã\x80\x82', 'å½¼å¥³ã\x81¯ã\x81\x93ã\x82\x93ã\x81ªé\x9b£ã\x81\x97ã\x81\x84æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x82èª\xadã\x82\x81ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x80\x82', 'ã\x83\x88ã\x83\x9eã\x81\x95ã\x82\x93ã\x81¯å°\x8få\xad¦ç\x94\x9få\x90\x91ã\x81\x91ã\x81®æ\x9c¬ã\x81\x8cèª\xadã\x82\x81ã\x82\x8bã\x81\x90ã\x82\x89ã\x81\x84æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92ã\x81\x9fã\x81\x8fã\x81\x95ã\x82\x93è¦\x9aã\x81\x88ã\x81¦ã\x81\x84ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x80\x82', 'ä¸\xadå\x9b½ã\x81§ã\x81¯æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®å\xad\x97æ\x95°ã\x81\x8cå¤\x9aã\x81\x84ã\x81\x8bã\x82\x89 è¤\x87é\x9b\x91ã\x81ªç¹\x81ä½\x93å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92ã\x82\x84ã\x82\x81ã\x81¦è¦\x9aã\x81\x88ã\x82\x84ã\x81\x99ã\x81\x84ç°¡ä½\x93å\xad\x97ã\x81«ç½®ã\x81\x8dæ\x8f\x9bã\x81\x88ã\x80\x81è\xad\x98å\xad\x97ç\x8e\x87ã\x82\x92é«\x98ã\x82\x81ã\x82\x8bã\x81\x93ã\x81¨ã\x81\x8cç°¡ä½\x93å\xad\x97æ\x8e¨é\x80²ã\x81®ç\x9b®ç\x9a\x84ã\x81§ã\x81\x97ã\x81\x9fã\x80\x82', 'ï¼\x94ç´\x9aã\x81®æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92ã\x81©ã\x82\x8cã\x81\xa0ã\x81\x91è¦\x9aã\x81\x88ã\x81¦ã\x81\x84ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x81\x8bã\x80\x82', 'ã\x81\x9dã\x82\x93ã\x81ªæ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81¯å\x83\x95ã\x81\x8cèª\xadã\x82\x81ã\x81ªã\x81\x84ã\x81»ã\x81©ã\x81\x9fã\x81\x84ã\x81¸ã\x82\x93è¤\x87é\x9b\x91ã\x81ªã\x82\x93ã\x81\xa0ã\x80\x82', 'æ\x97¥æ\x9c¬èª\x9eã\x81¨ä¸\xadå\x9b½èª\x9eã\x81®æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®ç\x99ºé\x9f³ã\x81¯ã\x81¨ã\x81¦ã\x82\x82é\x81\x95ã\x81\x84ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x81\xadã\x80\x82', 'ç§\x81ã\x81¯æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92å\x8b\x89å¼·ã\x81\x97ã\x81¦ã\x81\x84ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x80\x82', 'æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x82\x92èª\xadã\x82\x80ã\x81®ã\x81¯é\x9b£ã\x81\x97ã\x81\x84ã\x81§ã\x81\x99ã\x80\x82', 'ã\x81\x93ã\x81®æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®èª\xadã\x81¿ã\x81\x8bã\x81\x9fã\x81¯ä½\x95ã\x81§ã\x81\x97ã\x82\x87ã\x81\x86ã\x81\x8bã\x80\x82', 'æ\x97¥æ\x9c¬ã\x81§ã\x81¯å®\x89ã\x81\x84æ¼¢å\xad\x97ã\x81®è¾\x9eæ\x9b¸ã\x81\x8cã\x81\x82ã\x82\x8cã\x81°ã\x80\x81è²·ã\x81\x84ã\x81¾ã\x81\x99ã\x80\x82']
```

Comment: Where exactly is error? I would suggest you to decode text with`utf-8` or any other that will match japanese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get information with BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/sentences.cfm?j=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97&e=&search=Search+%3E'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('.jp'):
    print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
今日は漢字の書き取りがある。
漢字を書くときは点やはらいに気をつけて、なるべく早くていねいに書きましょう。
横着しないで、教わった漢字を使いなさい。
「道」という漢字の総画数は何画ですか。
彼は漢字が全く書けない。
君はこの漢字が読めますか。
漢字は読むのが難しい。
この漢字はどういう意味ですか。
いかにもリゾートってかんじの格好ね。
漢字を少し教えてください。
彼女はこんな難しい漢字も読めます。
トマさんは小学生向けの本が読めるぐらい漢字をたくさん覚えています。
中国では漢字の字数が多いから 複雑な繁体字をやめて覚えやすい簡体字に置き換え、識字率を高めることが簡体字推進の目的でした。
４級の漢字をどれだけ覚えていますか。
そんな漢字は僕が読めないほどたいへん複雑なんだ。
日本語と中国語の漢字の発音はとても違いますね。
私は漢字を勉強しています。
漢字を読むのは難しいです。
この漢字の読みかたは何でしょうか。
日本では安い漢字の辞書があれば、買います。
```

Note: It also depends on your terminal, if it can display Unicode characters. If you see garbled text, try to set your terminal to UTF-8.